# How to animate text within a button

Tags: android, animation

I would like to have text within a button blink/pulsate on and off. I know I can use `AlphaAnimation` to achieve this effect, but from what I know this acts on the entire button view. Is there a way to implement this type of animation on just the text within the button?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could animate the text color from your standard color to transparent and back again

```
ObjectAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myButton, "textColor", Color.RED, Color.TRANSPARENT); 
colorAnim.setDuration(1000); 
colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());     
colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE); 
colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE); 
colorAnim.start();
```

Comment: I don't need to implement this anymore, but can you provide some code how to do this for anyone that searches in the future.

Comment: `ObjectAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myTextView, "textColor", Color.RED, Color.BLUE);
colorAnim.setDuration(1000);
colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
colorAnim.start();`

Comment: Perfect that works. Can you edit your answer to add your code to it and I'll mark it resolved. Thanks